# Best way to handle image loading in custom list in android

Tags: android, picasso, custom-lists

I am working on a application where i need to show a user list. The user list is a custom list which have a imageview and textview. User image will be loaded in this imageview from server. I already worked with picasso library and which is really easy. I fetch the image url along with username from server using http request. Now the fact is as i need to use custom list i have implemented a custom adapter and in getView method i load the image using

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(container);
```

But my now question is when i need to show 30 user in list then i need to fetch 30 user image by above code. I don't know is this best practice or other way to handle such list. Again i don't know this list may occupied user memory. What can i do know?

Comment: Go have a look at Volley. It's a Google developed library that helps with exactly this http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html

Comment: Ever used Pojo? Try using that.

Comment: I have not used Pojo.- Tushar

Comment: Neil can i get a link of any complete tutorial of custom list using volley?

Comment: @Asif follow this link is a very good tutorial for implementing volley
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to Universal Image Loader:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

It is very customizable and comes with memory caching out the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Universal Image loader library to display images in your custom adapter.

There you can use this code to display image.

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView, new ImageLoadingListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage)
            {
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view)
            {
            }
        });
```

Here you can see [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: Which one will be better to use universal loader or use volley?

Answer (score 0):

Picasso library is easy to use and implements a cache as well, so your resources are not wasted.

I use this library in a list view with many items and it works like a charm (the same way you are doing).

As getView is invoked when the item becomes visible (as user scrolls mainly) there won't be lots of images downloading at the same time.

My recomendation is to keep using Picasso and to implement the [View holder](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) pattern in your list view adapter (you'll improve performance and get smooth scrolls).

--- UPDATE -----------------------------------------------------------

ViewHolder pattern brief example based in [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html):

"findViewById" uses a loop to traverse items inside a view, so when you scroll a list view there are many invocations to it from "getView". It might causes bad performance problems in big lists.

Listview reuse view items, that's because getView receives a View parameter. This parameter is null the first time it's used, but later previously used views can be passed to this method.

The idea of View Holder is to store references to the subviews when the main view object is created, so there's no need to invoke findViewById in future uses.

Follow these steps:

1. Implement a class to hold view references:

   static class ViewHolderItem {
       TextView textViewItem;
       // Add as many items as you need: check boxes, image views, ...
   }
2. Implement getView in your adapter this way:

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

   ```
   // First time: the object is created
   if(convertView==null){
       // inflate the layout
       LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
       convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

       // Creates the ViewHolder and stores references to views
       viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
       viewHolder.textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);

       // Uses tag to store the holder with the main view.
       convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
   } else {
       // View is beign resused.
       // Avoids calling findViewById() just use the viewHolder.
       viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
   }

   // Gets object item.
   ObjectItem objectItem = getItem(position);

   // assign values (if the object is not null)
   if(objectItem != null) {
       // Fill data in layout assigning values to views in the view holder.
       viewHolder.textViewItem.setText(objectItem.itemName);
       // Set images, check boxes state, or whatever you have in your layout.
   }

   // Finally returns the updated view.
   return convertView;
   ```

   }

Comment: Thanks. I already used picasso. Can you help me to use viewholder to improve the performance?

Comment: Check the two first steps in the link I provided: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

(I don't have an own implementation to share as I use annotations library and it implements that in a different way)

Comment: I updated my answer adding a brief example and explanation. Hope that helps.